# Manual LOOCV vs cv.glm

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation

In [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) we're asked to do the [Leave Out One Cross Validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27456/168153)  over logistic regression manually.  The code for it is here:

```
count = rep(0, dim(Weekly)[1])
for (i in 1:(dim(Weekly)[1])) {
##fitting a logistic regression model, not including ith data in the training data
    glm.fit = glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2, data = Weekly[-i, ], family = binomial)

    is_up = predict.glm(glm.fit, Weekly[i, ], type = "response") > 0.5

    is_true_up = Weekly[i, ]$Direction == "Up"
    if (is_up != is_true_up) 
        count[i] = 1
}
sum(count)
##[1] 490
```

The source of this code can be found [here](http://blog.princehonest.com/stat-learning/ch5/7.html).

Which means that the error rate is approximately 45 %.
But when we do it, using the `cv.glm()` function of the `boot` library, the result is far different.

```
> library(boot)
> glm.fit = glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2,data=Weekly,family=binomial)
> cv.glm = cv.glm(Weekly,glm.fit)
> cv.glm$delta
[1] 0.2464536 0.2464530
```

Why does this occur? What does the `cv.glm()` function exactly do?

Comment: Probably, you need to provide the cost function to compute the classification error since the default setting computes the mean squared error.  Check out the last paragraph of `?boot::cv.glm`.  The example there looks very similar to your case.

Comment: Okay! Thanks @KotaMori.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there may be a bug in the cv.glm function.  On line 23 it calculates
`cost(glm.y, fitted(glmfit))` where `fitted(glmfit)` are fitted *probabilities*.  In order to calculate cross-validated error rate (= total number of misclassified observations over n), we first need to map these to classes.  In other words, if you replace

`cost.0 <- cost(glm.y, fitted(glmfit))`

with

`cost.0 <- cost(glm.y, ifelse(fitted(glmfit)>0.5, 1, 0))`

I believe you should get the same thing as what you coded up manually.